# Netbeans Entity Manager not updating Derby Database

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I am currently using the automatically created class and Entity manager which is created when a table is bound to a database from NetBeans to get and set values to a derby database.
However when I want to update/edit the field using:

```
LessonTb Obj = new LessonTb();
        Obj.setAdditionalResources(Paths);
        Obj.setDescription(LessonDescription);
        Obj.setLessonName(LessonName);
        Obj.setLessonPath(LessonName + ".txt");
        Obj.setRecommendedTest(RecommendedTest);
EUCLIDES_DBPUEntityManager.getTransaction().begin();
EUCLIDES_DBPUEntityManager.getTransaction().commit();

lessonTbList.clear();
lessonTbList.addAll(lessonTbQuery.getResultList());
```

The current Entry does not update in the database despite knowing that the code worked in other projects. I use the same get and set methods from the same `LessonTb` class which works to add a new entry and delete and entry.

What could possibly be wrong and how do I solve my problem? No exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Here's several possibilities. Perhaps you can do more research to rule at least some of them out:

1. You're using an in-memory database, and you didn't realize that all the database contents are lost when your application terminates.
2. You're not in auto-commit mode, and your application failed to issue a `commit` statement after making your update
3. You're not actually issuing the update statement that you think you're issuing. For some reason, your program flow is not reaching that code.
4. Your update statement has encountered an error, but it's not the sort of error that results in an exception. Instead, there's an error code returned, but no exception is thrown.
5. There are multiple copies of the database, or multiple copies of the schema within the database, and you're updating one copy of the database but querying a different one.

One powerful tool for helping you diagnose things more deeply is to learn how to use -Dderby.language.logStatementText=true and read in derby.log what actual SQL statements you're issuing, and what the results of those statements are. Here's a couple links to help you get started doing that: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/tuning/rtunproper43517.html and http://apache-database.10148.n7.nabble.com/How-to-log-queries-in-Apache-Derby-td136818.html